# conditional statement in sql error in C# [offTopic]

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a login system by using parameterised sql and cross-table query.

This is my code for my login in C#:

```
private void userloigin() {

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=**;port=***;database=***;username=***;password=***;")) {

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student, teacher WHERE (student.Username = @userName AND student.Password = @passWord) OR (teacher.username = @teacherUser AND teacher.password = @teacherPass);");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textboxUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", texBoxPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherUser", textboxUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherPass", texBoxPassword.Text);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader DBReader;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int check = 0;
        while (DBReader.Read()) {
            var teacherLogin = DBReader.GetString("username");
            var teacherPass = DBReader.GetString("password");
            var studentLogin = DBReader.GetString("Username");
            var studentPass = DBReader.GetString("Password");

            if (teacherLogin == textboxUsername.Text && teacherPass == texBoxPassword.Text) {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull!");
                this.Hide();
                Registration ss = new Registration();
                ss.Show();
            } else if (studentLogin == texBoxPassword.Text && studentPass == texBoxPassword.Text) {
                MessageBox.Show(" Login Successfull");

                this.Hide();
                Test ss = new Test();
                ss.Show();
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect.  Try Again please");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Since username and password is in BOTH tables 'teacher' and 'student'. The login will allow the student to login BUT not the teacher. Which is understandable. However when I do:

```
tbl_name.col_name
```

I get an error saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data
>
> Additional information: Could not find specified column in results: teacher.username

```
 var teacherLogin = DBReader.GetString("teacher.username");
 var teacherPass = DBReader.GetString("teacher.password");
 var studentLogin = DBReader.GetString("student.Username");
 var studentPass = DBReader.GetString("student.Password");
```

QUESTION:

How can I amend my code so that if the 'teacher' signs in then take the teacher to the registration form.

Same way, if a student signs in then take the student to the test form?

What am I doing wrong?

```
     using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=project;username=root;password=Greenford123;"))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student.studentUsername, student.studentPassword, teacher.teacherUsername, teacher.teacherPassword FROM student, teacher WHERE (student.studentUsername = @userName AND student.studentPassword = @passWord) OR (teacher.teacherUsername = @teacherUser AND teacher.teacherPassword = @teacherPass);");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textboxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", texBoxPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherUser", textboxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherPass", texBoxPassword.Text);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader DBReader;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (DBReader.Read())
            {
                var teacherLogin = DBReader.GetString("teacherUsername");
                var teacherPass = DBReader.GetString("teacherPassword");
                var studentLogin = DBReader.GetString("studentUsername");
                var studentPass = DBReader.GetString("studentPassword");

                if (teacherLogin == textboxUsername.Text && teacherPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull!");

                    this.Hide();
                    Registration ss = new Registration();
                    ss.Show();
                }
                else if (studentLogin == texBoxPassword.Text && studentPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Login Successfull");

                    this.Hide();
                    Test ss = new Test();
                    ss.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect.  Try Again please");
                }

            }
```

EDIT:
its working now BUT it only allows the teacher access to the system. If the student tries to login it will say

> wrong username or password. try again please

Comment: You are getting that error because the query returns column names as the actual column names. Example If you run the query (Assuming you have MSSQL) in the MSSQLSM Studio, you'll see the column headers as `Username` `Password` not `teacher.username` etc etc

Comment: so I need to make a query which gets the values in the column name?

Comment: I guess in this case MSSQL and MySQL have similar behaviour. Try to specify columns to select instead of `*`.

Comment: The same thing. Run your query manually to check. The Columns will return `Username` `Password`. You are instructing the program to look for a column named `teacher.username` etc etc. which throws an error.

Comment: okay, ill give it a go

Comment: Its working now BUT it only allows teacher to login. It does not allow Student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because of this

```
else if (studentLogin == texBoxPassword.Text && studentPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
```

Where `studentLogin == texBoxPassword.Text` hence the

> wrong username or password.

Correct this instead with

```
else if (studentLogin == textboxUsername.Text && studentPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
```

Comment: No problem friend. I was hoping you would notice it and waited to see if someone else would point it out in the comments.